# Could megalomania and paranoia be two sides of the same coin?

Tags: abnormal-psychology

I'm a total layman so I am probably way off, but I've tried looking and not found much, so I figured I'd try asking here.

Is it possible that megalomania and paranoia could be different expressions of the same thing? They are clearly very different, but they both center on the idea that the person experiencing the psychosis or delusion is special and the center of attention.

So I started thinking that maybe it's like a self-defense mechanism for narcissists. That sometimes the real world simply can't meet their demand for narcissistic supply, so they invent some sort of alternate reality where they really are special, and the object of everyone's attention.

It struck me that when this happens, if a person is covert subtype, their imagined reality is one of persecution and they become paranoid, whereas if the person is a grandiose narcissist they become megalomaniacs.

As I said, I only have some anecdotal data to lean on here, but figured maybe this was something known or suspected in the field, or perhaps it's something that can be falsified and put to rest. I don't know.

I also wondered if maybe this connects to attachment types, and you could therefore potentially predict what sort of childhood someone had based on the kind of non-schizophrenic psychosis/delusion they exhibit.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.